# Angular7 - mat-tab-group with ng-container makes scrolling not to work on mobile

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-material, angular7, angular-material2

I'm using `mat-tab-group` with `ng-container` in order to display a list of custom components.

for some reason the combination of `mat-tab-group` with `ng-container` makes scrolling not to work:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>

<mat-tab>
    <ng-template matTabLabel>
        <div [matBadge]="mybadge" matBadgeOverlap="false">test</div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let obj of myArray">
        <my-component [prop]="obj.prop"></my-component>
    </ng-container>
</mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

I've also tried to override the `.mat-tab-body-content` css with:

```
.mat-tab-body-content { display: flex; flex:1; overflow-y: scroll !important; flex-direction: column }
```

Comment: This shouldn't be any problem. What are you doing in `my-component`? How are you fixing the height of the tab group component?

Comment: my-component contains few divs with some content. Very simple component. The height is fixed with height: 100px. The scroll is not working on mobile.

Comment: If it works on desktop but not on mobile - you need to make that clear in your post and title. I can't test on mobile. Try displaying just text instead of your component and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Sorry, I will fix the title. and yeah I'm can't make it work also without a custom component.